# Create a limit frequency response range WAV file FFmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, wav

I've been experimenting with using FFmpeg to convert modern high-quality audio (44.1, 48 & 96kHz etc.)into analogue type audio which are the old fashions Hi-Fi sounds like the 20 kHz frequency sampling signals https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHS#Hi-Fi_audio_system.

But since I already figured out how to simply convert high frequency (source 48kHz) to low frequently (output 20kHz) using the '-ar' filter:

`ffmpeg -i "source.webm" -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 20000 "output.wav"`

However, what I would like to know is how can I make a genuine "flat full-range frequency response" 20 Hz to 20 kHz?

That would mean first downmixing to 20kHz and also removing the first 20Hz out of the audio.

Comment: You probably want to use a bandpass or high-pass filter... https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#highpass

Comment: A 44.1kHz sampling rate is *already* 20-20Khz "flat full-range frequency response". The difference from that to any of the higher rates is inaudible. Reducing the rate to 20kHz will reduce the audio frequency limit to 10kHz… with a shed-load of aliasing noise unless you low-pass filter first. You need to read up on [Nyquist theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) before wasting your time any further.

Comment: I see, Well thanks I'll look into these features.